# Use of possessive in complex sentence

Tags: possessives, adverb-placement

> "It won't fall only on my shoulders, but also on the company that I'll be working for."

Is this sentence correct or does it need to show possession on the second sentence, like "on the company's (shoulder) that I'll be working for"?

Also, how does the meaning of the sentence change in the different positionings of "only"? E.g., it won't fall only on my shoulders; it won't only fall on my shoulders; it won't fall on my shoulders only.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct.  "Company" is parallel to "my shoulders", which is reasonable.

It would be somewhat odd to say "the company's"  as that would suggest "The company's shoulders", which is stretching the metaphor: do companies have shoulders?

If you want to avoid the parallelism, you could rephrase to something like:

> It won't fall only on my shoulders, but will also damage the company that I work for.